# Does this notation have a special meaning?

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently reading a paper and I don't know how to interpret this notation you can see on the screenshot.

http://moxn.brainex.de/pub/dfg.png

**Do the pointy angle brackets have a special meaning or did the author choose them just to confuse me?**

I googled it and apparently they are commonly used in group theory, which does not make much sense to me here.

Thanks for your input.

btw: The paper is called "A Formal Definition of Data Flow Graph Models" by Kavi, Buckles and Bhat, and is available [here](http://csrl.unt.edu/~kavi/Research/IEEE-TC-1986.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No special meaning here. The angle brackets simply denote a tuple or pair. The author chose the angle brackets to look prettier than the usual round parentheses. Thus a graph $G$ is a set of vertices $A \cup L$ and a set of edges $E$.

Comment: Ok, I thought so too but did not want to take the chance of interpreting it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It's standard to use angle brackets where the things to the rights are dependent on things to the left, as in this case, and, say, in the definition of an algebraic structure.  For something like Cartesian coordinates, normal parentheses are more normal.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know that. Thx

Comment: It's a bit sloppy, because apparently they mean for A and L to be the two sides of a bipartition but their notation doesn't actually express that. One sometimes sees something more like (A,L,E) for denoting bipartite graphs, for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Angle bracket is often used to represent the pairing function.
Find more information herehttps://mathworld.wolfram.com/PairingFunction.html.